# mysql subquery for charts

Tags: mysql, group-by, subquery

I have 2 tables with the following data

inviteTable

```
inviteDate  | contractAmount | status

2014-01-01     1500             awarded
2015-01-01     2000             awarded
2015-01-02     4000             closed
2015-02-01     6000             awarded
2015-02-02     8000             awarded
2015-03-01     8500             awarded
```

quoteTable

```
quoteDate  | quoteAmount | status

2014-03-01     1500         awarded
2015-01-02     2000         awarded
2015-01-03     4000         sent
2015-01-04     6000         awarded
2015-02-03     8000         awarded
2015-02-10     8500         sent
2015-02-11     9000         awarded
2015-03-01     9500         awarded
```

I want to make **ONE** query that gives me the following data structure

```
month   | quotedTotal | quotedCount | awardedTotal | awardedCount

January      8000           2             2000            1
February    17000           2            14000            2
March        9500           1             8500            1
```

currently i have written this code...but it doesn't work

```
  SELECT
    MONTHNAME(t1.due_date) as month,
    (select sum(`amount`) from quoteTable where awarded= 1 ) as estimatedAmount,    
     sum(t1.contactAmount) AS sumContactAmount,
     COUNT(*) as `noOfAwarded`

    FROM inviteTable t1 

    where

    t1.status = "Awarded" and 
    t1.inviteDate between '2014-11-01' and '2015-10-31'

 GROUP BY MONTH(due_date)
    ;
```

basically I want to have **ONE** query that gives me the following:

1. volume that got awarded - sum of contractAmount and status awarded
2. count of how many awarded - count of inviteTable.status=awarded
3. volume that got quoted - sum of quoteAmount and status awarded
4. count of how many quoted - count of quotedTable.status=awarded

all grouped by month and in a date range

my query doesn't work.  Your help would be highly appreciated as I am stuck!

Comment: Please provide `fiddle` link to represent your tables and data, this can help every one to find the solution easily.

Comment: @user2062455 You are looking for [`HAVING`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp), though you should also mention how is it not working.

Comment: One another question the result must match for both table or not for example is there possible that for `January` only one of the tables has record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your schema is unfortunate; it would be easier if you have just one table with an extra column to record what type of record you have. However, if you first collect the two tables into one table via `union all`, you can use a fairly simple query to produce the results to want:

```
select
  monthname(_date) month,
  sum(quoteAwarded * amount) quotedTotal,
  sum(quoteAwarded) quotedCount,
  sum(contractAwarded * amount) awardedTotal,
  sum(contractAwarded) awardedCount
from (select inviteDate _date, contractAmount amount, status = 'awarded' contractAwarded, 0 quoteAwarded from inviteTable
  union all
  select quoteDate, quoteAmount, 0, status = 'awarded' from quoteTable) x
where _date between '2014-11-01' and '2015-10-31'
group by 1
order by month(_date)
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/51503/5) using your sample data, and producing you expected output.

At the core of this query is the convenient fact that (in mysql) "true" is 1 and "false" is 0 - allowing the use of `sum()` instead of `count()`, and more importantly avoiding the use of `case` by using `sum()` over some simple math.

Comment: unfortunately i cannot have all my data in one table.  your solutions worked like a charm.  Abhik's update works also but yours is with less code.  thank you both for your input

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way you can do it, note that you have dates in both tables and you need to use join preferably `left join` , so this will ensure that the dates present in the left table is always returned in this case the month name.

```
select
t1.month,
t1.awardedTotal,
t1.awardedCount,
t2.quotedTotal,
t2.quotedCount 
from(
  select
  monthname(t1.inviteDate) as month,
  month(t1.inviteDate) as m,
  sum( 
    case 
     when t1.status = 'awarded' then t1.contractAmount else 0
    end
  ) as awardedTotal,
  sum( 
    case 
     when t1.status = 'awarded' then 1 else 0
    end
  ) as awardedCount
  from inviteTable t1 
  where t1.inviteDate between '2014-11-01' and '2015-10-31'
  group by month 
)t1 
left join(
  select
  monthname(t2.quoteDate) as month,
  sum( 
    case 
     when t2.status = 'awarded' then t2.quoteAmount else 0
    end
  ) as quotedTotal,
  sum( 
    case 
     when t2.status = 'awarded' then 1 else 0
    end
  ) as quotedCount
  from quoteTable t2 
  where t2.quoteDate between '2014-11-01' and '2015-10-31'
  group by month
)t2 on
t1.month = t2.month
order by t1.m
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a863a/10

UPDATE:
Yes since you want dates present in both tables it can not be done with the above process since it always consider one table as left table and will get all the dates from that table. For getting data for all the dates across both tables you first need to get the dates from both tables and then using left join get the calculation part something as

```
select
t1.month,
coalesce(t2.awardedTotal,0) as awardedTotal,
coalesce(t2.awardedCount,0) as awardedCount,
coalesce(t3.quotedTotal,0) as quotedTotal,
coalesce(t3.quotedCount,0) as quotedCount
from(
  select month(inviteDate) as m,monthname(inviteDate) as month 
  from inviteTable where inviteDate between '2014-11-01' and '2015-10-31'
  union
  select month(quoteDate) as m,monthname(quoteDate) as month
  from quoteTable where quoteDate between '2014-11-01' and '2015-10-31'
)t1
left join(
  select
  monthname(inviteDate) as month,
  sum( 
    case 
     when status = 'awarded' then contractAmount else 0
    end
  ) as awardedTotal,
  sum( 
    case 
     when status = 'awarded' then 1 else 0
    end
  ) as awardedCount
  from inviteTable 
  group by month 
)t2 on t1.month = t2.month
left join(
  select
  monthname(quoteDate) as month,
  sum( 
    case 
     when status = 'awarded' then quoteAmount else 0
    end
  ) as quotedTotal,
  sum( 
    case 
     when status = 'awarded' then 1 else 0
    end
  ) as quotedCount
  from quoteTable 
  group by month
)t3 on t1.month=t3.month
order by t1.m
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ddaac/14

Comment: this doesn't work if i have dates with months that exist only in one table.  see the exmaple:  [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ddaac/1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ddaac/1)

Comment: I should have made it a bit more clear.  I am trying to have a list of all months and the data of awardedTotal, awardedCount, quotedTotal, quotedCount in the corresponded months

Comment: @user2062455 yes if you need all the dates across the tables then you need to modify the query, check the updated answer.